# Please add an RSS feed of bounty questions and answers

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, bounties, feed

One thing that would be useful would be to have an RSS feed of whenever a question has a bounty put on it and when that question is decided. This would be a good way of featuring such questions and probably wouldn't be too noisy either.

Comment: Ah, the quesiton - the particle responsible for the confusion force. :)

Comment: I would ask the OP to put a bounty tag on the question and look at the feed for the bounty tag.

Comment: The problem with that solution is that it cuts into the 5 tag max.

Comment: It seems that there is now an RSS feed, but there are some problems when it is used in chat: [Why doesn't this feed for featured questions work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/230594)

Answer (score 2):

The featured question feed is available on the home page on the appropriate tab -- see bottom of that page.