# Why doesn't this feed for featured questions work?

Tags: bug, chat, bounties, feed

I've created [this feed user](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/-246/big-shot) a little more than four months ago.
It is supposed to post [featured questions](https://anime.stackexchange.com/feeds/featured) from [Anime & Manga](https://anime.stackexchange.com/). However, it never worked.

The feed <s>is currently empty, since we have no featured questions right now</s> **currently has two questions**. However, whenever there are featured questions, nothing gets posted in [the chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6697/maid-cafe-). The feed, however, does add the questions as they get bounty'd.

[We've tried](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/14755949#14755949) temporarily adding a feed and a new user to post featured questions from SO, and that one worked.
Also, all our [other feeds](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/6697/maid-cafe-?tab=feeds) do work too.

Comment: I may or may not have encountered the same bug. On [French](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/1098/chez-cosette?tab=feeds) we have a [feed user](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/-147/french-language--forte-recompense) for posts with bounties as well. It [used to work](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/-147/french-language--forte-recompense?tab=recent) but the last post was on May 12 (and there have been bounties since).

Comment: This is still an issue. [The Nineteenth Byte](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/240/the-nineteenth-byte?tab=feeds) has a *Featured Questions* feed, yet no questions get posted in the chat room.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is kinda complicated - there are two parts to it: one is what chat does with feeds and the second is how bounties work and how question feeds work.

On the chat side - chat remembers the time it last checked a feed, so the next time it runs it will get the feed and only show items in the feed that were published *after* that date. (if it it a new feed and doesn't have a last run date it will pick up the newest 5 items in the feed - regardless of age).

On the featured feed side - the publish date of an item is the time a question was *created*, not the time a bounty was added to it.

Now, because bounties cannot be posted immediately (there is a 2 day waiting period), the publish time of a featured item will be at least 2 days old.

And since chat checks each feed for updates multiple times a day, the featured items get filtered out as they are older than the last run time.

---

Thing is - each part works correctly. This is the correct behaviour by chat and the correct behaviour by the feed generator.

So - the problem is one of timing... and not strictly a bug.

Comment: Isn't this kind of saying it's broken by design? If a properly implemented news reader would be useless (as it seems to be) then maybe the data should be adjusted so that it actually can be consumed in a way that's useful—like maybe dating things in the featured feed with the bounty dates.

Comment: It is not by design - more of an unfortunate set of incompatible features, each working correctly on their own. The problem with getting bounty dates - it isn't a cheap thing to do with our data model :/

Comment: I think the bug is the hack done of ignoring feed items older than the last run time. As far as I know, there are other feed readers that don't pull that stunt, and instead go ahead and check GUIDs or links against all previous entries to see if they're duplicates.

Comment: @NathanO'TᴇstingTuggy - consider what the feeds in chat would look like if we did not do so. We do have to filter things out.

Comment: @Caleb - that's essentially what I ended up doing. Will see once we build out.

Comment: @Oded: I get that you don't want to show the same thing more than once. That's pretty straightforward. But if you're deliberately dropping items that fit a particular very simple rule on the floor to reduce average load… well, I'm not sure how that's anything other than a really bad design decision. Maybe feeds should be throttled and items beyond a certain rate get randomly dropped. That would still be unreliable, but at least it would be reliably so.

Comment: Uh? What? The point is to not show the same thing multiple times - at least, that's how I read the code and why this was done.